# Web api stops after some time but works when I republish it but then again it stops after some time

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, publish

I am experiencing a weird issue with web api on VS2013. When I publish the api in local IIS, it works perfectly but stops working after some time and throws this error

> Could not load file or assembly 'Reporting.Models, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies.
>   Access is denied.

I have checked Reporting.Models DLL, it exists but the strange thing is if I republish, the api works perfectly but again after sometime it complains the same error.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Sounds weird but restarting Visual Studio helps from time to time when using the buggy publish feature.

Comment: It sounds like the web server user account does not have acces to some libraries

Comment: Ok, thanks. It shouldn't even work immediately after publishing if user account does not have access to the libraries? why does it work for sometime then?

Answer (score 0):

It's just been resoled. After looking at the event log, I realized that unhandled exception was causing IIS to crash. I put an exception and it seems to be working consistently.